# Loop Keyword Program Homework

Tags: java, loops, helper

It will ask the user for a keyword to search for. Then, it will ask the user to enter sentences over and over. The user can stop the process by typing “stop” instead of a sentence (which means, of course, that we can’t analyze the one word sentence ‘stop’, but that is OK). Once the user has finished entering the sentences, the program should display the following statistics:

1. The total number of sentences entered
2. The total number of sentences that contain the keyword
3. The average starting position of the keyword in the sentences that contain the keyword.

Can somebody help me put this program together? For #3 we only do average position of the sentences that contain the keyword.

I have the loop part, and for #3 I'm guessing we would use indexOf. #2 inputString.contains(keyword) I'm guessing? Can somebody help me with 1-3 and putting them into a Java program? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String keywordString;
        String inputString;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numofSentences = 0;
        int numofKeyword = 0;                       
        System.out.println ("Enter a keyword. We will search each sentence for this word.");
        keywordString = keyboard.nextLine ();
        System.out.println ("Please enter a sentence or type 'stop' to finish");
        inputString = keyboard.nextLine ();
        while( !inputString.equals ("stop"))
        {       
            if(inputString.contains (inputString));
            numofSentences = numofSentences + 1;
            if(inputString.contains (keywordString));
            numofKeyword = numofKeyword + 1;
            System.out.println ("Enter a line of text or 'stop' to finish");
            inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println ("You entered " + numofSentences + " sentences");
        System.out.println ("You have " + numofKeyword + "sentences that contain the keyword");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm really new to Java. This is my first semester doing programming, so I'm not quite sure how to include my code on here.

Comment: copy and paste are your friends

Comment: If I copy and paste it, it doesn't come in code form. Right now I just wrote the basis of the program. How do I format the code to paste it in here?

Comment: There are instructions on the edit page.  You're looking for the {} button.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I figured it out. I have the loop done correctly, and the counting number of sentences. But I have a problem with the keyword counter. When I type a keyword in when I run the program, no matter what I enter for the sentence, it adds +1 to the counter. So if I type 3 sentences, even if they don't include the keyword it comes up as 3. If I type 4, it outputs 4. Etc.

Anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I like having self-documenting code, so here are a couple suggestions for how you can have a nice tight main loop:

**functional-ish semantics**

```
public void loop() {
  // TODO: ask for the keyword and store it somewhere

  while(true) {
    try {
      updateStatistics(checkOutput(getSentence()));
    } catch (EndOfInput) {
      printStatistics();
    }
  }
}
```

**Object-Oriented**

```
public void loop() {
  String keyword = myPrompter.getNextSentence();
  myAnalyzer.setKeyword(keyword);

  while (true) {
    String sentence = myPrompter.getNextSentence();
    AnalysisResult result = myAnalyzer.analyze(sentence);
    if (result.isEndOfInput()) {
      myAnalyzer.printStatistics();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

What both of these approaches gives you is a simple framework to plug in the specific logic. You could do all of it inside the main loop, but that can get confusing. Instead, it's preferable to have one function doing one task. One function runs the loop, another gets the input, another counts the # of sentences, etc.

Sometimes I'll start with those little functions, and build the app from the bottom-up, so I'd write a method that takes a string and returns true/false depending on if it's the string "stop". You can even write unit tests for that method, so that when you're building the rest of the app, you know that method does what you intended it to. It's nice to have lots of modular components that you can test along the way, rather than writing a huge long loop and wondering why it's not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to prompt the user for an initial input then enter in to a loop that will last until the user presses stop (or whatever), in each iteration you need to prompt the user for a sentence, if the user inputs data increment one counter that stores the number of sentences, test the sentence against the keyword entered and increment a second counter as applicable, you will also need to push the position that the word occured in to a stack to later get the average which should be the sum of the stack divided by the size. you should be able to use `indexOf()` to get the position.

Comment: Hey Tom, I just included my code. I think I messed up with the keyword String as it's not correctly outputting whether or not the user inputs a keyword in their sentence. See anything wrong with it?

Comment: hello your very close I think you just need to jiggle it around a bit and add an array to hold the positions for part 3 of the assignment, you don't need the condition in the while statement you could just break the loop when the user inputs "stop", also use brackets for your if/else blocks :)

Comment: You don't need to keep a track of the positions (you have only been asked to ouput average position and it's unlikely you will be needing the data later for any other statistical analysis so just keep a running total of position and divide by sentences with term in @user1276514

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I don't know how to get the sentences with the term in it. I must have messed up somewhere because it's not giving me the correct output of sentences that contain the key word.

Answer (score 0):

```
package console;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Console {

    static float averagePositionInSentence = 0;
    static String searchTerm = "";
    static int noOfSentencesEntered = 0;
    static int noOfMatches = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        searchTerm = writeToConsoleAndReturnInput("Add phrase to search for.");
        writeToConsole("Now type some sentences. To exit type the word 'stop' on its own");
        mainInputLoop();
        outputResults();
    }

    public static void mainInputLoop() {

        boolean ended = false;
        while (!ended) {
            try {
                String input = readLineFromConsole();
                if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                    maintainStatisticalData(input);
                } else {
                    ended = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                writeToConsole("There was an error with your last input");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void outputResults() {
        writeToConsole("You entered " + noOfSentencesEntered + " sentences of which " + noOfMatches + " conatined the search term '" + searchTerm + "'");
        writeToConsole("");
        writeToConsole("On average the search term was found at starting position " + (averagePositionInSentence / noOfSentencesEntered) + " in the sentence");
    }

    public static void maintainStatisticalData(String input) {
        noOfSentencesEntered++;
        if (input.contains(searchTerm)) {
            noOfMatches++;
            int position = input.indexOf(searchTerm)+1;
            averagePositionInSentence += position;
        }
    }

    //terminal helper methods
    public static void writeToConsole(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static String writeToConsoleAndReturnInput(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        try {
            return readLineFromConsole();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //should do something here
            return "Exception while reading line";
        }
    }

    public static String readLineFromConsole() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);

        return in.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a common idiom, but using the abbreviation 'no' to mean 'number' has always rubbed me the wrong way. When I read it, I read it as 'no of matches'. I imagine you added the 'of' so that it wouldn't read as 'no matches' which one would assume would be a boolean flag, but this kind of defeats the purpose of abbreviating in the first place. Why not just call it 'matches', or 'numMatches' or 'matchCount' if you must?

Comment: agreed - but using # (not allowed) or No (not camelCase) or matches (?) i.e. matches bool... I should just use number and be done with it but I take your point