# Java Loop Keyword Contain

Tags: java, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop Keyword Program Homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958703/loop-keyword-program-homework)

s I'm having a problem with this program. The user will enter a keyword, and then after that will enter a sentence. I need the program to output how many sentences contain the keyword, and the average starting position of the keyword in the strings. This is what I have so far. Whenever the program outputs, it doesn't give me the correct # of times the keyword is entered. It just gives me the # of sentences. Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String keywordString;
        String inputString;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numofSentences = 0;
        int numofKeyword = 0;                       
        System.out.println ("Enter a keyword. We will search each sentence for this word.");
        keywordString = keyboard.nextLine ();
        System.out.println ("Please enter a sentence or type 'stop' to finish");
        inputString = keyboard.nextLine ();
        while( !inputString.equals ("stop"))
        {       
            if(inputString.contains (inputString));
            numofSentences = numofSentences + 1;
            if(inputString.contains (keywordString));
            numofKeyword = numofKeyword + 1;
            System.out.println ("Enter a line of text or 'stop' to finish");
            inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println ("You entered " + numofSentences + " sentences");
        System.out.println ("You have " + numofKeyword + "sentences that contain the keyword");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from the readers? The entire solution cooked for you or a fix for a bug that you really cannot find? Please precise what you expect.

Comment: I'd hope somebody could just explain to me what I'm doing wrong that is causing the output to not correctly keep the number of sentences that contain the user inputted keyword. I'm really new to Java, so I know this is beginner stuff.

Comment: Dont put semi-colons after your if statement headers: `if(inputString.contains (inputString)); <-- no ';'`

Comment: Hunter...any idea how I find the average starting position of the keyword in each sentence that contains the keyword. If statement of input string containing keyword string and then output the index?

Comment: On this website, new questions should be created separately. Also, you are supposed to ask only when you already tried everything you could to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe without the `;` after the `if` statements it will work better :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a keyword. We will search each sentence for this word.");
    String keywordString = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence or type 'stop' to finish");
    String inputString = keyboard.nextLine();

    int numofSentences = 0;
    int numofKeyword = 0;                       
    while (!inputString.equals("stop"))
    {       
        if (inputString.contains(inputString))
            numofSentences++;
        if (inputString.contains(keywordString))
            numofKeyword++;

        System.out.println("Enter a line of text or 'stop' to finish");
        inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println ("You entered " + numofSentences + " sentences");
    System.out.println ("You have " + numofKeyword + "sentences that contain the keyword");
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's the 2nd time I've made this mistake and I didn't even notice it when tracing through. Thanks for the help Vincent.

Now for the 3rd part.

I need to find the average starting position of the keyword, but only in the sentences that contain the keyword. So if statement, input string contains keyword string.

How do I output the indexOf the keywordString?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the right answer as a solution on this website. Thank you.