# Java Keyword Average Position

Tags: java, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop Keyword Program Homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958703/loop-keyword-program-homework)

I'm trying to find the average starting position of the user inputted keyword in a string. I've tried using indexOf() but I can't seem to initialize it correctly. Can somebody help me here?

An example of the output I'm looking for would be: The average starting position is 4.5

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String keywordString;
        String inputString;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numofSentences = 0;
        int numofKeyword = 0;                       
        System.out.println ("Enter a keyword. We will search each sentence for this word.");
        keywordString = keyboard.nextLine ();
        System.out.println ("Please enter a sentence or type 'stop' to finish");
        inputString = keyboard.nextLine ();
        while( !inputString.equals ("stop"))
        {       
            if(inputString.contains (inputString));
            numofSentences = numofSentences + 1;
            if(inputString.contains (keywordString));
            numofKeyword = numofKeyword + 1;
            System.out.println ("Enter a line of text or 'stop' to finish");
            inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println ("You entered " + numofSentences + " sentences");
        System.out.println ("You have " + numofKeyword + "sentences that contain the keyword");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you actually get?  What did you learn when you stepped through your program in the debugger?

Comment: I tried doing

   averagePosition = indexOf(keywordString);

But that didn't work. Do I need to initialize a variable like I did with numofSentences and numofKeyword?

Comment: Like I know how to get the indexOf a word in a string, but the problem is that I don't know how to do a user inputted keyword.

Like I could do indexOf("word") for example.

Comment: averagePosition = inputString.indexOf(keywordString));

Would that work?

Comment: It is better to test your hypothesis first before asking us.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 `if`s inside the `while` loop have a `;` at the end. You should delete them and try running the program again.

Comment: Or always use braces around if clauses!

Answer (score 0):

Scanner class do not give you a method to know where the pattern has occurred in the sentence. You have to use Pattern and Matcher class to find out the positions. As this is your homework i m not giving you code but an example on how to use patterns...

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Regex {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
     System.out.println("Pattern is " + m.pattern());
     while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.start() + " " + m.group());
     }
  }
```

}

This program uses the first command-line argument (args[0]) to represent the
regex expression you want to use, and it uses the second argument (args[1]) to
represent the source data you want to search. Here's a test run:

java Regex "56" "ab4 56_7ab"
Produces the output:

```
Pattern is 56
4 56
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We calculate average starting position by dividing (addition of all starting positions) by (total number of sentences containing keyword)

Here is the code for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Program to calculate the average starting position of a given keyword in user input sentences.
 * We calculate average starting position by dividing (addition of all starting positions) by (total number of sentences containing keyword)
 * @author Garbage
 *
 */
public class Lab6Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String keywordString;
        String inputString;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalSentences = 0;
        int interestingSentences = 0;
        int positionTotal = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a keyword. We will search each sentence for this word. : ");
        keywordString = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence or type 'stop' to finish");
        inputString = keyboard.nextLine();

        while (!inputString.equals("stop")) {
            totalSentences = totalSentences + 1; //totalSentences++

            // Check if the sentence contains our keyword
            if (inputString.contains(keywordString)){
                interestingSentences = interestingSentences + 1; // This is sentence we would like to check
                positionTotal = positionTotal + inputString.indexOf(keywordString); // Add the starting position to our total
            }
            System.out.println("Enter a line of text or 'stop' to finish");
            inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("You entered " + totalSentences + " sentences");
        System.out.println("You have " + interestingSentences   + "sentences that contain the keyword "+keywordString);
        System.out.println("The average starting position is "+(positionTotal / interestingSentences));
    }
}
```